# Python Iteration Returns No List - []

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, datetime

My goal for this script is to loop through hundreds of Excel and CSV files and find only file string names with "cash", that are CSV files, and between 2 date periods, formatted like YYYYMMDD. Once located, the script would pull the second row of the first worksheet down to the last row and append it to a master worksheet.

I am just returning empty for the list however. Is it due to the filepath? The file path is in a shared server so that may play a role in the error?

Thank you in advance recommendations!

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
from datetime import datetime

path = r'\\base\sub1\sub2\sub3\sub4\sub5\sub6\SearchFolder'

base_date = datetime(2020, 10, 1, 00, 00)
dates = pd.date_range(base_date, periods=92).tolist()
dates = [i.strftime("%Y%m%d") for i in dates]
list_of_csvs = glob(path+'*.csv')
print (list_of_csvs)
csvs_to_keep = []
for csv in list_of_csvs:
    if 'cash activities' in str(csv).lower():
        print ('cash activities found')
        for date in dates:
            if str(date) in csv:
                print (csv)
                csvs_to_keep.append(csv)
                    
master_df = pd.DataFrame()
for csv in csvs_to_keep:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv)
    master_df = master_df.append(df)
master_df.to_excel('master_file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Also your glob pattern is not correct, the way its written you're searching for the pattern: `...sub5\sub6\SearchFolder*.csv`, when you probably need: `...sub5\sub6\SearchFolder\*.csv` to actually search inside of your "SearchFolder".

Comment: Remark may not be relevant, but, by replacing  "\" par "/" maybe ?